# Auth0 External Provider

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, oauth, openid-connect

I want to achieve this funcionality using asp .NET
the admin enable the external identity provide and enter the needed parameter (clienId,client Secret) and immediatly the user of the appliation will be able to connect with this external provider
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tnBf.png)